# Neo4J Browser does not show any results on connecting with Java API

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm trying to connect to Neo4J using Java, and have been following this [sample demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-g-vCsZO_3g).

I setup a new Maven Project, and added the code which creates a few Nodes and Relationships among the nodes. This is how my main class looks like -

```
package neo4j;

import org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_3.No;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.*;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by manish on 5/15/17.
 */
public class Neo4JDemo {


    public enum NodeType implements Label {
        Person, Course, Dummy;
    }

    public enum RelationType implements RelationshipType {
        Knows, BelongsTo;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GraphDatabaseFactory databaseFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
        File file = new File("/home/manish/Documents/Development/Software/neo4j-community-3.1.4/data/databases/graph.db");
        GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = databaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(file);

        try(Transaction tx = graphDatabaseService.beginTx()) {
            Node bobNode = graphDatabaseService.createNode(NodeType.Person);
            bobNode.setProperty("PID", 5001);
            bobNode.setProperty("Name", "Bob");
            bobNode.setProperty("Age", 23);

            Node bNode = graphDatabaseService.createNode(NodeType.Dummy);
            bNode.setProperty("PID", 5001);
            bNode.setProperty("Name", "Bob");
            bNode.setProperty("Age", 23);

            Node aliceNode = graphDatabaseService.createNode(NodeType.Person);
            aliceNode.setProperty("PID", 5002);
            aliceNode.setProperty("Name", "Alice");
            aliceNode.setProperty("Age", 20);

            Node eveNode = graphDatabaseService.createNode(NodeType.Person);
            eveNode.setProperty("PID", 5003);
            eveNode.setProperty("Name", "Eve");
            eveNode.setProperty("Age", 25);

            Node itNode = graphDatabaseService.createNode(NodeType.Course);
            itNode.setProperty("ID", 1);
            itNode.setProperty("Name", "IT Beginners");
            itNode.setProperty("Location", "Room 154");

            Node ecNode = graphDatabaseService.createNode(NodeType.Course);
            ecNode.setProperty("ID", 2);
            ecNode.setProperty("Name", "Advanced Electronics");

            bobNode.createRelationshipTo(aliceNode, RelationType.Knows);

            Relationship bobRelIt = bobNode.createRelationshipTo(itNode, RelationType.BelongsTo);
            bobRelIt.setProperty("Role", "Student");

            Relationship bobRelEc = bobNode.createRelationshipTo(ecNode, RelationType.BelongsTo);
            bobRelEc.setProperty("Role", "Supply Teacher");

            Relationship aliceRelIt = aliceNode.createRelationshipTo(itNode, RelationType.BelongsTo);
            aliceRelIt.setProperty("Role", "Teacher");

            tx.success();
        }

        graphDatabaseService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

When I run the project, it compiles successfully -

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for neo4j:neo4j-setup:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 10, column 15
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building neo4j-setup 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ neo4j-setup ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/manish/Documents/Development/Thesis/Neo4J-Test1/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ neo4j-setup ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/manish/Documents/Development/Thesis/Neo4J-Test1/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.420 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-15T19:24:46-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/263M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, when I head over to the Neo4J Browser at `localhost:7474`, there are no nodes or relationships of the type that was created through this Java code -

[image]

I'm not sure what's going wrong, and would appreciate any help with this.

---

UPDATE - including `pom.xml` -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>neo4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-setup</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>neo4j-setup</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: suppose you are using a maven project it would be helpful if you can share the `pom.xml`. I think problem might lay there.

Comment: Sorry, just forgot to add. I've updated the question with pom.xml. Thank You.

Comment: Is it possible to verify if you are indeed pointing to the database you created ? With CALL dbms.listConfig(); in the browser you can show the configuration and see what data directory is used.